# What is the meaning of 'X tuned' in Linux terminal?

Tags: python, linux, terminal, fedora

In Linux terminal, I am using

```
pgrep -lf python
```

to see if there's any Python progress. Then after I perform

```
pkill -9 python
```

to kill all python scripts, I got this:

```
882 tuned
```

What is the meaning of this line?

Thanks !!!

Comment: Why on the earth you want to kill python?

Comment: Related: [Does 'tuned' need to keep running?](https://serverfault.com/q/712814/36240)

Comment: I am running some python script to continuously read data from some file, and I am modifying that script. So I think I need to kill it and restart in order to get the latest data ?...